# What does $\mbox{cholesky}(P)^{-1} [\cos(\theta), \sin(\theta)]$ correspond to?

Tags: matlab, python, ellipsoids, cholesky-decomposition

I'm trying to understand a function, and its name isn't really helping me (I've found resources similar to [this](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/elliplot/index.html) and [this](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ellipsoid.html) but this is either R or not exactly "ELLIPLOT" and I'm not sure I fully understand the concept of an elliplot).

I know what a Cholesky decomposition is but I can't understand the sort of link it has with ellipses. I guess I'm looking for resources or explanation as to what pan of mathematics this is related to. I've encountered this function in a Linear Programming course but we haven't done much more than writing it and I'm a bit confused as to why we did.

```
def ellipplot(P,gamma=None,xc=None):
    """Matlab ELLIPPLOT Internal function for plotting ellipsoid"""
    if xc is None:
        xc = np.zeros(len(P))
    if gamma is None:
        gamma = 1 
    P=P/gamma
    P=np.linalg.cholesky(P)
    theta = np.linspace(-3.14, 3.14, 1000)
    z = np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])
    x = np.linalg.inv(P)@z
    for n in range(x.shape[1]):
        x[:,n]=x[:,n]+xc
        xe = x[0,:]
        ye = x[1,:]
    return xe, ye

xe, ye = ellipplot(
    np.array(
        [[2, 1], 
         [1, 2]]
    )
)
plt.plot(xe, ye)
plt.show()
```

This is the [matlab version of the function](https://github.com/EnricoGiordano1992/LMI-Matlab/blob/master/yalmip/extras/ellipplot.m), I believe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The ellipse is defined by
$$
p_{11}x_1^2+p_{22}x_2^2+p_{12}x_1x_2+p_{21}x_1x_2=1\,.
$$
In matrix/vector notation this is
$$\tag{1}
x^\top Px=1
$$
where
$$
P=\left(\begin{matrix}p_{11}&p_{12}\\p_{21}&p_{22}\end{matrix}\right)\,,~~x=\left(\begin{matrix}x_1\\x_2\end{matrix}\right)\,.
$$
To plot the points that satisfy (1) the code takes the Cholesky decomposition (square root) of $P=LL^\top$ so that (1) can be written as
$$\tag{2}
y^\top y=1\,~~\text{ where }y=L^\top x\,.
$$
Clearly,
$$
y=\left(\begin{matrix}\cos\theta\\\sin\theta\end{matrix}\right)\,\quad\quad\theta\in[-\pi,\pi]
$$
satisfy (2). Therefore, to find the vector $x$ we onyly have to invert $y=L^\top x$ and that's what the code does.

Strictly speaking the code inverts $L$ (not $L^\top$) but I checked that it plots an ellipse.

Comment: Thanks for the answer!

Comment: A little question though, why is it $p_{11}x_1^2+p_{22}x_2^2+p_{12}x_1x_2+p_{21}x_1x_2=1$ in your first equation (the one without a number)? Is it just what the code does? If I had changed `z = np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])` by `z = 3*np.array([np.cos(theta), np.sin(theta)])`, would your first equation become $p_{11}x_1^2+p_{22}x_2^2+p_{12}x_1x_2+p_{21}x_1x_2=9$?

Comment: Let me answer this with a hint: if you multiply the vectors, $x$ or $y$ with a constant, or $L$ how does this affect $P$ , hence the first equation ?  To see how that affects the ellipse geometrically you can also just plot it again. Feel free to ask but it is not that hard I think.

Comment: Sorry that hint was unnecessary. It *does* become $p_{11}x_1^2+p_{2s}x_2^2+p_{12}x_1x_2+p_{21}x_1x_2=9.$

Comment: I know the question was a bit naive, but because I was not 100% sure I figured I may as well ask it. Probably should've plot it though! Thank you for your help!